# how to update elements on the original file so the user can see progress as progress is being made on the processing file

Tags: php, jquery

I am becoming more and more familiar with jQuery, however, I haven't been able to figure this out.

I have a page which collects the data and sends the data to a processing file through jQuery.  Here is the Code...

```
$( "#start_it" ).click(function(){
            var url = 'grunt/process.php';
            var keywords = $("#keywords").val();        
            var providers = $('input[name="providers"]:checked').map(function (){return this.value;}).get().join(",");
            var networks = $('input[name="networks"]:checked').map(function (){return this.value;}).get().join(",");
            var ex_ct = $("#ex_ct").val();
            var list_type = $("#list_type").val();
            var shuffle = $("#shuffle").val();      
            var postit = $.post( url, {
                keywords:keywords,
                providers:providers,
                networks:networks,
                ex_ct:ex_ct,
                list_type:list_type,
                shuffle:shuffle             
                });     
            postit.done(function( data ) {alert(data);});       
        });
```

On the process.php it loops through each provider and within the provider loop it loops through each network. What I would like to do is to be able to show progress being made to the user who is on the collection page while process.php is processing behind the scene at the start of every loop. here is the code:

```
foreach($providers as $provider){
        $pros = explode(',',$provider); foreach($pros as $pro){

            // I WANT TO BE ABLE TO UPDATE A DIV ON THE 
            // COLLECTION PAGE TO TELL THEM WHICH PROVIDER 
            // THE SCRIPT IS PROCESSING HERE



            foreach($networks as $network){ 
                $nets = explode(',',$network); foreach($nets as $net){

                // I WANT TO BE ABLE TO UPDATE A DIV ON THE 
                // COLLECTION PAGE TO TELL THEM WHICH NETWORK 
                // THE SCRIPT IS PROCESSING HERE





                } # $nets as $net
            } # $networks as $network
        } # $pros as $pro
    } # $providers as $provider
```

I have search both the internet and Stack but I guess my queries have not been clear as the returns have been far different from the desired information.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Pete

Comment: There are a number of ways this can be approached, some of which depends on how your server is configured. Have you tried any polling or long polling?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by polling or long polling/

Comment: @petebolduc long polling is making a request to the server that takes a long time to timeout

Comment: @jcuenod Thanks... I am going to have to research that one for sure... the processing here is lengthy... actually it really doesn't go to the server at all... it is a lead generation script that extracts data through file_get_contents() in php. Then it is made available though immediate pdf download

Comment: If you want to try to use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) you can take a look here: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-without-polling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to indicate progress, you would need a server response updating you incrementally.

It's not impossible but **depending on the data you're sending**, it's not worth it. Server calls and responses are costly and you should want to minimise them so unless you are uploading a lot of data (like a video or perhaps audio file) it's better *not* to keep hitting the server.

To solve this people typically use spinners (which indicate *indefinite* progress).

Comment: Design wise I agree that this is much easier, but it doesn't really answer the OP's question. In some cases you want more information, example: batch video processing or very large uploads.

Comment: I was planning on using a spinner if I could not figure it out but a competitor to the script is show progress on the fly and altough not absolutely necessary I thought it woud be good if I did as well

Comment: @petebolduc what sort of data is it because if it submits fast it's really pointless making multiple hits on the server

Comment: Another design option to go alongside the spinner is just a simple JS timer to indicate how long the job is taking. Usually all the user wants to see is that something is happening, assuming the job goes by very quickly on average.

Comment: @MariM it's an alternative solution and it explains why a progress bar is an inferior option. True, you could use a timer but a countdown is used UX-wise because it gives the impression of a definite endpoint.

Comment: ... actually it really doesn't go to the server at all... it is a lead generation script that extracts data through file_get_contents() in php. Then it is made available though immediate pdf download